# How to get rrule.between() to only include start timestamp

Tags: python, python-dateutil

How would I create an rrule that excludes only the end timestamp using dateutil? Would I have to create a custom function or is there a way to do it natively?

here is an example

```
rule = rrule.rrule(rule.HOURLY,tsstart=somedate,until=somedate_four_hours_later)
```

I want the output to EXCLUDE `somedate_four_hours_later` and only generate 4 timestamps, somedate, somedate+1 hour, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example?  What is the RRULE that you are working with?  Can you set the start date and a [duration](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/duration-t.html)?

Comment: ``rrule`` means recurrence rule, see: `<https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57>`_.

Comment: yes, I know that. I am looking to create a recurrence rule where the until=end_time is excluded, but the start timestamp is included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an [`rruleset`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html#dateutil.rrule.rruleset), which allows you to combine recurrence rules and specific dates as required. In this case, what you'd do is set the `until` date as an `exdate` (excluded date):

```
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dtstart = datetime(2015, 1, 3, 12)
dtuntil = datetime(2015, 1, 3, 16)

rr = rrule.rrule(freq=rrule.HOURLY, dtstart=dtstart, until=dtuntil)

# Add your rrule to the ruleset, then exclude the until date from the rule set
rrset = rrule.rruleset()
rrset.rrule(rr)

l1 = list(rrset)
rrset.exdate(dtuntil)

l2 = list(rrset)

print(l1[-1])   # 2015-01-03 16:00:00
print(l2[-1])   # 2015-01-03 15:00:00
```

The `rrule` itself will include the `until` date, but the `exdate` will exclude it from the `rruleset`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the count:

```
In [1]: from dateutil import rrule

In [2]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta

In [3]: st = datetime(2016, 7, 5, 23, 30)

In [4]: rule = rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, st, count=4)


In [5]: print(list(rule))
[datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 5, 23, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 0, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 1, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 2, 30)]
```

Or use *timedelta* adding three hours to the start:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

st = datetime(2016, 7, 5, 23, 30)
rule = rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, st, until=(st + timedelta(hours=3)))
```

Comment: So there is no way to just exclude the until timestamp?

Comment: @sakurashinken, yes, if you have an end just timedelta-1 hour

Comment: So there is no native equivalent of .between() that only excludes endpoints, but includes startpoints?

Comment: Not that I know of, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a flag like inc=False that would set the only the endpoints to be excluded.

Comment: @sakurashinken, there is when you use between, the default is actually  False but there is no such flag for rrule